# How to concatenate string fields to one field with a delimiter in rails 4 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, concatenation

I have multiple checkboxes in form, in which I store the results of every field in their corresponding temporary fields which I specified in model with attr_accessor: attribute. I want to join the contents of these fields into one field with a comma delimiter and store that into database.

My complete form is something like this :

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>
  <% if @company.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@company.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this company from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @company.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>


  <p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
               <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name,class:'form-control' %>
  </p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :grade %><br>

    <%= f.select(:grade, options_for_select([['Dream', 'dream'], ['A++', 'a++'], ['A+', 'a+'],['A', 'a']])) %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :beCutoff %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :beCutoff,class:'form-control' %>


    </p>
    <%= f.label :branchesAllowed %><br>
 <%= f.check_box :coe, {}, "COE", "" %><%= label_tag :COE %><br>

  <%= f.check_box :ece,  {}, "ECE", ""%><%= label_tag :ECE %><br>
  <%= f.check_box  :ice, {}, "ICE", ""%><%= label_tag :ICE %><br>
  <%= f.check_box  :it,  {}, "IT", ""%><%= label_tag :IT %><br>
  <%= f.check_box :mpae, {}, "MPAE", ""%><%= label_tag :MPAE %><br>
  <%= f.check_box  :bt, {}, "BT", ""%><%= label_tag :BT %><br>
  <%= f.check_box  :is, {}, "IS", ""%><%= label_tag :IS %><br>
  <%= f.check_box  :sp,  {}, "SP", ""%><%= label_tag :SP %><br>
  <%= f.check_box  :pc,  {}, "PC", ""%><%= label_tag :PC %><br>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :backsAllowed %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :backsAllowed,class:'form-control' %>
  </p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :details %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :details,class:'form-control' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :package %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :package,class:'form-control' %>
  </p>
   <p>
    <%= f.label :xiiCutoff %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :xiiCutoff,class:'form-control' %>
  </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :xCutoff %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :xCutoff,class:'form-control' %>
  </p>
  <%= f.label :deadline %><br>

                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>

                    <%= f.text_field :deadline ,class:'form-control',:readonly=>true%>
                    <span class="input-group-addon" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss '});
            });

        </script>

    </div>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>



<% end %>
```

I specified fields :coe,:ece,:ice, etc in my model as attr_accessor:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

     attr_accessor :coe,:ece,:ice,:it,:mpae,:bt,:is,:pc,:sp


     validate :deadline_on_or_before_now

  def deadline_on_or_before_now
    errors.add(:deadline, "can't be in the past") if
      !deadline.blank? and deadline < (Time.zone.now+19800).to_datetime
  end

    validates :name, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 2 };
    validates :grade,:beCutoff,:details,:package, presence: true;
    validates_inclusion_of :beCutoff,:xiiCutoff,:xCutoff, :in=> 0..100,:message=>"Out of Range";

end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @company = Company.new
    end

    def edit

        @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @company = Company.find(params[:id])

        if @company.update(company_params)
            redirect_to @company
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def create

        @company = Company.new(company_params)

        if @company.save
            redirect_to @company
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def index
        @companies = Company.all
    end
    def destroy
        @company = Company.find(params[:id])
        @company.destroy

        redirect_to companies_path
    end

    def show
        @company = Company.find(params[:id])

    end


    private
        def company_params

            params.require(:company).permit(:name, :beCutoff,:grade,:xiiCutoff,:xCutoff,:backsAllowed,:details,:package,:deadline,:branchesAllowed,:coe,:ece,:ice,:it,:mpae,:bt,:is,:sp,:pc) if params[:company]
        end
end
```

I want to join :coe,:ece,:ice, etc fields and store it into :branchesAllowed(string field) field with a commma delimiter and able to split this field whenever I need use them separately.
I am using postgresql with rails 4.1.

Comment: I don't want to mess with the code again, so of course a method that let me do a one time change method would help. But I would like to know both methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **quickest and dirtiest** way would be to simply concatenate the fields in a method in your model and to call that method in a `before_save` callback:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  # . . .

  before_save :combine_branches   # or choose other callback type respectively
  def combine_branches
    self.branchesAllowed = ""
    self.branchesAllowed += "COE" if coe
    self.branchesAllowed += "ECE" if eve
    self.branchesAllowed += "ICE" if ice
    # … and so on … 
  end
end
```

Now when you call `save` or `update` in your controller the callback triggers and sets the `branchesAllowed` field before writing to the database.

This, however, is not really dry nor easily expandable. If you want to add another branch you'd have to edit at least 3 different places.

A **dry**(er) solution could be something like the following:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  # keep a constant of possible branches tied to the model
  POSSIBLE_BRANCHES = [:coe, :ece, :ice, :it, :mpae, :bt, :is, :pc, :sp]

  # add the branches as virtual attributes (only assign methods)
  attr_writer *POSSIBLE_BRANCHES

  # add virtual attributes reader methods
  # --> define every branch as method, that looks if the value is currenly
  # stored in the branchesAllowed string and return true or false
  POSSIBLE_BRANCHES.each do |pb|
    define_method(pb) do
      self.banchesAllowed.split(',').include?(pb.to_s.upcase)
    end
  end

  # add the callback to combine the branches
  before_save :combine_branches
  def combine_branches
    self.banchesAllowed = POSSIBLE_BRANCHES.select { |pb| !!self.send(pb) }.map(&:upcase).join(',')
  end
end
```

Then you can also use them in your view:

```
<%= f.label :branchesAllowed %><br>
<% Company::POSSIBLE_BRANCHES.each do |pb| %>
  <%= f.check_box pb, {}, pb.to_s.upcase, "" %><%= label_tag pb.to_s.upcase %><br>
<% end %>
```

So, if you want to add another branch later on you'd simply add another symbol to the array constant and you're done. Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

Since `boolean` values in checkboxes use `'1'` and `'0'` (as strings) by default, I'm not entirely sure if the virtual attribute reader methods should return that instead of a boolean value.

Comment: I used both the ways and they worked. Just applied some if conditions and everything was perfect. Thanks

Comment: It would be great help if you tell any way in which I retrieve the options checked or unchecked when i edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to do it this way, I'd go for a hash stored in a string field.

```
before_save :create_string

def create_string
    fields = {}
    fields[:coe]=coe
    fields[:ece]=ece
    # etcetera
    branchesAllowed = fields.to_s # hash to string and then store the string
end
```

And then, to retrieve values (let's say in a controller or a view):

```
values = eval(@company.branchesAllowed) # reversely, evaluate string to hash
@coe = values[:coe]
@ece = values[:ece]
# etcetera
```

Comment: I tried @vapire way to solve and worked for me and your solution looks similar to that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this slightly differently. Assuming these are all attributes of a `Company` that you want to be able to set, you could use a single integer field to store this data by creating an array of the attribute types and using the index of each attribute in that array as a binary value, which you can use to identify whether an attribute is set or not.

Watch this Railscast for a complete explanation since Ryan does it much better than I would: http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association

Comment: Thanks @Jon I appreciate your help. I tried arrays earlier in my application too but I found somewhere that arrays are not good things in rails. Also I want a quick fix to this application.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using an Array in Rails. Also, you should prefer the right fix over a quick bodge.